# Getting TypeError in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2, typeerror

I am writing a simlpe web application in Python using GAE. My `response.out.write` is giving me `TypeError`. The error message is:

```
self.response.out.write(*a, **kw)
TypeError: write() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

The python code is:

```
import os

import jinja2
import webapp2

template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir))

class Handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def write(self, *a, **kw):
        self.response.out.write(*a, **kw)

    def render_str(self, template, **kw):
        t = jinja_env.get_template(template)
        return t.render(kw)

    def render(self, template, **kw):
        self.write(self, self.render_str(template, **kw))

class MainHandler(Handler):

    def get(self):
      self.render("shopping_list.html", name="steve")


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler),],
                             debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly pass `self` to the `write()` method.

Replace:

```
self.write(self, self.render_str(template, **kw))
```

with:

```
self.write(self.render_str(template, **kw))
```